# AngualrJS, Karma, Jasmine - how to write a test for a service function that calls $q.all?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a service function that calls 2 http urls and then once both has been resolved sets some data in the service.

E.g.

```
    function dataServicesCall() {
        var start = moment(dateDataModel.date).format('YYYYMMDD');
        var end = moment(dateDataModel.date).format('YYYYMMDD');

        var promises = [
            DataService.getClients(),
            DataService.getProjects(start, end)
        ];

        $q.all(promises)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(' a ');
                setItems(response[1]);
            })
            .catch(handleError);
    }
```

What I am doing in my unit test is mocking both of the DataServices calls and trying to mock the response.

```
fit('should get the data for the current day upon starting up', function() {

    var spy = spyOn(DataService, 'getProjects').and.callFake(function () {
        console.log(' == hi ');
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve([]);
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    var spy1 = spyOn(DataService, 'getClients').and.callFake(function () {
        console.log(' hi ');
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve([]);
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    myService.dataServicesCall();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); //ok
    expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled(); //ok

    expect(mService.items).toEqual([]); //not ok

});
```

The problem is that the $q.all is never called in my service and the setItems function is never called. I am not sure how to complete this unit test.

Comment: You should call $rootScope.$digest() in order to execute a promise chain in tests.

Comment: Hi, that cased another error for me: Error: Unexpected request: GET ./js/home/confirm.html No more request expected
            at $httpBackend (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1403:9)

Comment: And this becomes totally different question. That was covered on SO a lot of times. Search for `"Unexpected request: GET"`.

Comment: Hi, it didn't help too much because I am not using template caching at the moment. I do have one abstract route though.

Comment: Well, you should use template caching if you have templates. The alternative is to refactor the application to not use routing in unit tests at all.

Comment: Oh but I didn't, I got that error when I did $rootScope.$digest no idea why I am testing a service

Comment: Your test affects entire application instead of a single unit. You should have multiple modules if you want to test units separately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154903/discussion-between-user1261710-and-estus).